# CSS - If image is in area of a div, then cut off that piece which is in area?

Tags: css

So I have an picture, which is under my `div` element, but is this possible, if picture goes under that, div that part will be hidden (cut off)?

Comment: yes, you have to set background color of your div....

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the part of image that out of a div with css:

```
.divclass {overflow:hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If you have an Object A (image or text or both), and a DIV B that overlaps A in the browser window:

- Set position:relative and z-index: on both of them (position:absolute will also work, if it preserves your layout), such that the value of B's z-index is greater that that of A. This ensures that B really is stacked on top of A, not under it. For example, this CSS:

  img#A {

  ```
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
  ```

  }

  div#B {

  ```
  position:relative;
  z-index:200;   /* Can be any number larger than the z=index of #A */
  ```

  }
- You must also set a background color for B, because a default (which sometimes is transparent) background will not obscure anything. Decide if you might want the background color to be the same color as the rest of the page, or a different color.
- BONUS: if you want to make A *slightly* show through B's background, specify the color as RGB with an Alpha (opacity) value. In CSS, a 30% translucent white background would be, for example, like this CSS:

  div#B {

  ```
  position:relative;
  z-index:200;   /* Can be any number larger than the z=index of #A */
  background-color:#fff; /* For downlevel browsers */
  background-color:rgba(256,256,256,0.3); /* The last argument is for opacity, the valid range is from 0 to 1. */
  ```

  }

Note that we provide a default, solid-white background (#fff) first, to support any browsers that still aren't quite up to speed on the RGBA syntax. The translucent version here -- rgba(256,256,256,0.3) -- comes after that, so it will supersede the opaque background in all browsers that support the RGBA declaration; all other browsers will still overlay/obscure your object but without translucency.